# Creating a Generic HashMap Array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, hashmap

For a homework assignment which is stated as:

In this homework, you will implement a key-value hash map with a external chaining collision policy. A
hash map maps keys to values and allows O(1) average case lookup of a value when the key is known.
This hash map must be backed by an array of initial size 11, and must have a size of 2n + 1 when the
table exceeds (greater than, not greater than or equal to) a load factor of 0.67. The array must be resized
before the new key (regardless of whether or not it’s a duplicate) is actually added into the array. The
load factor and initial size values are provided as constants in the interface and should be used within
your code.

We're given a MapEntry class already written, and a HashMap class to write up. How would I intialize this array? `private MapEntry<K, V>[] table = new MapEntry<>[STARTING_SIZE];` doesn't work because of the generics situation.

Comment: Array or hashmap, which one is it? Theyre not the same

Comment: @TimCastelijns A HashMap backed by an array, we can't use the Java Object

Comment: @laune you will implement a key-value hash map with a external chaining collision policy.
This hash map must be backed by an array of initial size 11, and must have a size of 2n + 1 when the
table exceeds (greater than, not greater than or equal to) a load factor of 0.67. The array must be resized
before the new key (regardless of whether or not it’s a duplicate) is actually added into the array. The
load factor and initial size values are provided as constants in the interface and should be used within
your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omit the generic parameters in the array constructor:

```
Map.Entry<String,Integer>[] entries = new Map.Entry[11];
```

You can use an annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` if the warning bothers you.

Comment: Okay so even though it gives an Unchecked assignment warning it'll still be good?

Comment: @newacct Oops. Instant blackout. Thanks.